# OpenGL default value for unbuffered vertex attribute when using layout qualifiers

Tags: opengl, attributes, shader, vertex-buffer

I'm assuming this will be one of those things that is "undefined", but I can't seem to find a concrete answer from google.

Let's say in my vertex shader I have:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 vColour;
```

But there is nothing buffered to location 2 with glEnableVertexAttribArray() or glVertexAttribPointer(). Can I expect the value to be anything particular?

I was assuming for a vec4 that it would be along the lines of {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1} or {1,1,1,1}, but in my case it is {0,0,1,1}.

When I previously used glBindAttribLocation() to specify the locations, it defaulted to {1,1,1,1} on 4 different machines using 3 different operating systems (ubuntu 12.04, windows 7, and ubuntu 10.04).

Is it safe to assume the value will be {0,0,1,1} across machines? or was this simply a coincidence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can I expect the value to be anything particular?

Yes, it is a particular value.

Assuming that you *correctly* turned off the attribute array (ie: with [`glDisableVertexAttribArray`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnableVertexAttribArray) on that attribute index), the value you get comes from the [in-context vertex attribute](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Non-array_attribute_values), as set by the [`glVertexAttrib`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttrib) suite of functions. These are global context state, not stored within the VAO.

By default, they all start at (0, 0, 0, 1). However, if you have rendered with a particular attribute using an *array* in that attribute index, the context value is effectively destroyed. So you should reset the context value if you want to use it.

Comment: So i have set glDisableVertexAttribArray() for the particular location number, but it still is read in the shader as {0,0,1,1}. I'm using a VAO, so I only make the call once. Should I disable them right before I my glDrawElements() call instead?

Comment: @Pondwater: If the VAO disables it, then it's disabled. You don't have to disable it again. Also, I made an addendum to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

They are kind of undefined here, but that might not be a problem. There GL state consists of the `CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB` values. Initially, they are (0,0,0,1). You can explicitely set the attribute values for those attribs where no array is enabled via the [`glVertexAttrib()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttrib.xml) family of functions.

The only thing to worry is what happens to the current values when the attribute array is actually enabled during drawing. To quote the [Spec (Version 3.3)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.pdf), Section 2.8.3 Vertex Arrays - Drawing Command:

> If an array corresponding to a generic attribute required by a vertex shader
>   is not enabled, then the corresponding element is taken from the current generic
>   attribute state (see section 2.7).
>
> If an array corresponding to a generic attribute required by a vertex shader is
>   enabled, the corresponding current generic attribute value is undefined after the
>   execution of `DrawArraysOneInstance`.

So jou just have to specify a useful value after you had drawn with an array enabled for that particular attribute.

**UPDATE**

This behavior has actually changed beginning with [OpenGL 4.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec42.core.pdf):

> If an array corresponding to a generic attribute required by a vertex shader is
>   not enabled, then the corresponding element is taken from the current generic attribute
>   state (see section 2.7). Otherwise, if an array is enabled, the corresponding
>   current generic attribute value is **unaffected** by the execution of DrawArraysOneInstance.

So now, a `glDraw*()` call will never modify the currently set attribute values.

Comment: "*They are kind of undefined here, but that might not be a problem. There GL state consists of the CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB values.*" So how does that make them "kind of undefined"? It isn't undefined if the spec *defines them*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I was refering to the fact that the values are undefined after you render with the attrib array enabled (as by the spec), which I assume the OP was doing, since otherwise they would have been on the default values if he does not even know about `glVertexAttrib`.